# Python - How to bind custom endpoint Flask-Restful

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create my first API using python + flask-restful and I'm getting an error when I call a custom endpoint.

For example, I have the code bellow:

```
from app import db, app
from app import manager
from datetime import datetime
from flask import jsonify

class Climate(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    rainfall = db.Column(db.Integer)
    temperature = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def predict():
        predictValue = Climate.query.filter_by(date=datetime.now().date())
        return predictValue

db.create_all()
manager.create_api(Climate, methods=['POST', 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
```

When I start run run.py and do the GET request -> http://localhost:8080/api/climate it returns to me the following:

```
{
  "num_results": 2, 
  "objects": [
    {
      "date": "2018-10-07T00:00:00", 
      "id": 1, 
      "rainfall": 100, 
      "temperature": 15
    }, 
    {
      "date": "2018-07-10T00:00:00", 
      "id": 2, 
      "rainfall": 200, 
      "temperature": 20
    }
  ], 
  "page": 1, 
  "total_pages": 1
}
```

So that is ok. But I want to do a custom endpoint. For example, if I call http://localhost:8080/api/climate/predict I want to call the predict() method in the Climate class to return just one item that binds the day of the request, but when I do this request, it just return

```
{}
```

Anyway to do that? Thanks.

Comment: please check the filter date=datetime.now().date(), I figured this condition didn't match any record.

Comment: Even if I change the condition, for example, to: rainfall=100 its still returning {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
# endpoint to predict
@app.route("/climate/predict", methods=["GET"])
def climate():
    climate = Climate.query.filter_by(date=datetime.now().date()).first()
    if climate is not None:
        return jsonify(serializeClimate(climate))
    else:
        abort(404)
```

All code here on github: https://github.com/danielnicolay321/ParetoTest/blob/master/crud.py